# sql server 2008 running totals between 2 dates

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to get running totals between 2 dates in my sql server table and update the records simultaneoulsy. My data is as below and ordered by date,voucher_no

```
DATE         VOUCHER_NO    OPEN_BAL   DEBITS   CREDITS    CLOS_BAL 
-------------------------------------------------------------------    
10/10/2017       1            100       10                  110    
12/10/2017       2            110                5          105
13/10/2017       3            105       20                  125
```

Now if i insert a record with voucher_no 4 on 12/10/2017  the output should be like

```
DATE         VOUCHER_NO    OPEN_BAL   DEBITS   CREDITS    CLOS_BAL
------------------------------------------------------------------    
10/10/2017       1            100       10                  110    
12/10/2017       2            110                5          105    
12/10/2017       4            105       4                   109
13/10/2017       3            109       20                  129
```

I have seen several examples which find running totals upto a certain date but not between 2 dates or from a particular date to end of file

Answer (score 0):

You should consider changing your database structure. I think it will be better to keep `DATE, VOUCHER_NO, DEBITS, CREDITS` in one table. And create view to calculate balances. In that case you will not have to update table after each insert. In this case your table will look like

```
create table myTable (
    DATE date 
    , VOUCHER_NO int
    , DEBITS int
    , CREDITS int
)

insert into myTable values
    ('20171010', 1, 10, null),( '20171012', 2, null, 5)
    , ('20171013', 3, 20, null), ('20171012', 4, 4, null)
```

And view will be

```
;with cte as (
    select
        DATE, VOUCHER_NO, DEBITS, CREDITS, bal = isnull(DEBITS, CREDITS) * case when DEBITS is null then -1 else 1 end
        , rn = row_number() over (order by DATE, VOUCHER_NO)
    from 
        myTable
)

select
    a.DATE, a.VOUCHER_NO, a.DEBITS, a.CREDITS
    , OPEN_BAL = sum(b.bal + case when b.rn = 1 then 100 else 0 end) - a.bal
    , CLOS_BAL = sum(b.bal + case when b.rn = 1 then 100 else 0 end)
from
    cte a
    join cte b on a.rn >= b.rn
group by a.DATE, a.VOUCHER_NO, a.rn, a.bal, a.DEBITS, a.CREDITS
```

Here's another solution if you can not change your db structure. In this case you must run update statement each time after inserts. In both cases I assume that initial balance is 100 while recalculation

```
create table myTable (
    DATE date 
    , VOUCHER_NO int
    , OPEN_BAL int
    , DEBITS int
    , CREDITS int
    , CLOS_BAL int
)

insert into myTable values 
('20171010', 1, 100, 10, null, 110)
,( '20171012', 2, 110, null, 5, 105)
, ('20171013', 3, 105, 20, null, 125)
, ('20171012', 4, null, 4, null, null)

;with cte as (
    select
        DATE, VOUCHER_NO, DEBITS, CREDITS, bal = isnull(DEBITS, CREDITS) * case when DEBITS is null then -1 else 1 end
        , rn = row_number() over (order by DATE, VOUCHER_NO)
    from 
        myTable
)
, cte2 as (
    select
        a.DATE, a.VOUCHER_NO
        , OPEN_BAL = sum(b.bal + case when b.rn = 1 then 100 else 0 end) - a.bal
        , CLOS_BAL = sum(b.bal + case when b.rn = 1 then 100 else 0 end)
    from
        cte a
        join cte b on a.rn >= b.rn
    group by a.DATE, a.VOUCHER_NO, a.rn, a.bal
)

update a
set a.OPEN_BAL = b.OPEN_BAL, a.CLOS_BAL = b.CLOS_BAL
from
    myTable a
    join cte2 b on a.DATE = b.DATE and a.VOUCHER_NO = b.VOUCHER_NO
```